# how to export a table of contents for tagged lines only

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Let's say my document has this motif:

```
* Heading 1           :sometag:
** Heading 1.1
*** Heading 1.1.1     :target:
* Heading 2           :target:
** Heading 2.1        :sometag:
```

When exporting (say, to HTML) I want the option of creating a Table of Contents with only the :target: lines exported.

Note that the :target: tags occur at all kinds of levels of headings, so there's no way to filter based on exporting headings only to a certain depth.

I'm looking for solutions based on Org-mode and Emacs (even if additional Emacs Lisp code is required), not solutions that entail preprocessing or filtering the file with scripts outside of Emacs, because of portability constraints.